# gulp css: SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

Tags: javascript, css, postcss

Why do I get this conclusion when using gulp css?

```
[hacl@devep brio]$ gulp css
/home/bitrix/www/brio-3/local/templates/brio/node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/Explorer.js:54
    for await (const place of this.config.searchPlaces) {
        ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bitrix/www/brio-3/local/templates/brio/node_modules/stylelint/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/index.js:12:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
[hacl@devep brio]$
```

Сode snippet from the file in which the error occurs:

```
  async searchDirectory(dir) {
    for await (const place of this.config.searchPlaces) {
      const placeResult = await this.loadSearchPlace(dir, place);

      if (this.shouldSearchStopWithResult(placeResult) === true) {
        return placeResult;
      }
    } // config not found


    return null;
  }
```

I tried to install a new version of Nodenv, but the error did not dare.
I updated node.js to version 16.9.1, before that it was 8.17.0
Now I am getting this error:

```
[gr@devep ext_www]$ cd brio-3/local/templates/brio/
[gr@devep bryno]$ gulp css
[09:12:54] Using gulpfile /home/bitrix/www/brio-3/local/templates/brio/gulpfile.js
[09:12:54] Starting 'css'...
[09:12:54] Starting 'lint-css'...
[09:12:54] Finished 'lint-css' after 160 ms
[09:12:54] Starting 'compile-css'...
[09:12:54] 'compile-css' errored after 36 ms
[09:12:54] Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/bitrix/www/brio-3/local/templates/brio/assets/dist/css/critical/about-critical.css'
[09:12:54] 'css' errored after 200 ms
[gr@devep bryno]$
```

фывфыв

```
    [gr@devep bryno]$ gulp css
    [10:16:33] Using gulpfile /home/bitrix/www/brio-3/local/templates/bryno/gulpfile.js
    [10:16:33] Starting 'css'...
    [10:16:34] Starting 'lint-css'...
    [10:16:34] Finished 'lint-css' after 294 ms
    [10:16:34] Starting 'compile-css'...
    [10:16:35] Plumber found unhandled error:
     Error in plugin "gulp-postcss"
    Message:
        PostCSS plugin postcss-assets requires PostCSS 8.
    Migration guide for end-users:
    https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
    Details:
        fileName: /home/bitrix/www/brio-3/local/templates/brio/assets/src/css/st.css
    
    Stack:
    Error: PostCSS plugin postcss-assets requires PostCSS 8.
    Migration guide for end-users:
    https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
        at Processor.normalize (/home/bitrix/ext_www/bryno-3d/local/templates/bryno/node_modules/gulp-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:167:15)
        at new Processor (/home/bitrix/ext_www/bryno-3d/local/templates/bryno/node_modules/gulp-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:56:25)
        at postcss (/home/bitrix/ext_www/bryno-3d/local/templates/bryno/node_modules/gulp-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:55:10)
        at /home/bitrix/ext_www/bryno-3d/local/templates/bryno/node_modules/gulp-postcss/index.js:50:16
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    [10:16:35] The following tasks did not complete: css, compile-css
    [10:16:35] Did you forget to signal async completion?
[gr@devep bryno]
```

After executing the command `npm i postcss`, the error is repeated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `node -v`
If the version is below 10.0.0, you should upgrade to a newer version.